# Syncing Google Account in Chrome gets "Paused" overnight

Tags: google-chrome

Since a couple of months back, when I close my computers for the night and open it the next morning, Google Chrome's sync via my Google Account is "Paused". It doesn't always happen, but it's very often so. I then need to login again with my password.
What could be the reason for this?

I have reviewed the Google Account "Recent security activity", but it doesn't show anything out of ordinary.

*NB: I'm running Google Chrome on MacOS and I have Bitdefender installed.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

Visit this page in Chrome

chrome://flags

Look for a flag called "Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar", and disable it.

Relaunch Chrome.

It should stop pausing daily but will pause once every two weeks or once a month.